# Svn Error on import time no space left on device

Tags: linux, subversion, aws

When I import file in svn repository I get following error .

```
svn: E000028: Failed writing updated file: No space left on device
```

Following is mine diskspace and inode details

```
 # df -i
    Filesystem      Inodes   IUsed   IFree IUse% Mounted on
    /dev/xvda1     5242880 2216389 3026491   43% /
    none            479859       2  479857    1% /sys/fs/cgroup
    udev            476898     379  476519    1% /dev
    tmpfs           479859     283  479576    1% /run
    none            479859      16  479843    1% /run/lock
    none            479859       1  479858    1% /run/shm
    none            479859       3  479856    1% /run/user
    overflow        479859      40  479819    1% /tmp

# df
Filesystem     1K-blocks     Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvda1      82438832 37065492  41917704  47% /
none                   4        0         4   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
udev             1907592        8   1907584   1% /dev
tmpfs             383888     2400    381488   1% /run
none                5120        0      5120   0% /run/lock
none             1919436        0   1919436   0% /run/shm
none              102400        0    102400   0% /run/user
overflow            1024       96       928  10% /tmp
```

Comment: You showed the inode usage but you didn't show the block usage. In my experience, running out of inodes is almost never the problem. You should check if you've run out of ACTUAL SPACE (by running `df` without `-i`). In any case, the error message is pretty self explanatory and your problem will surely disappear when you clear the `No space left on device` condition, so -1 from me.

Comment: @celada as per you mentioned please check  mine 'df' staus

Comment: Please step into the directory where you are importing the svn repo and run `df -k . -h`

Comment: @Johan output is following
{
 # df -k . -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvda1       79G   36G   41G  47% / }

Comment: Could be `svn` can out of space in `/tmp`? There are only 928KiB available, that's not a lot. I don't know if `svn` generally writes things to `/tmp` but it's the only filesystem I see that is tight on space. One way or the other, I would advise using a much larger `/tmp` filesystem.

Comment: Do you have disk quotas?

Comment: Was this ever solved? (Also seeing reports of out-of-space on a partition not out of space)